# Google Maps v3 API + jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, api

I'm trying to develop a Store Locator (using Google Maps v3 API), that's located in an expandable div. However, the map is not showing up properly (see link below). I'm a newbie to jQuery in general, so this is all a bit new to me.

I know there's a conflict though. As when I remove the ready function for the expandable div, the map will show up properly. But not with the call there.

All the code can be found here:

http://t-zonevibration.com/expandable_store_locator/

Is it a jQuery conflict? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question was reliant on an external link, which is now returning 404. That means the post is missing a [mcve] that is required to make it understandable. For now I will recommend that the question is put on hold, given how old it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#map` element must be visible in the page...

So you need to put the initialization code in the callback to the `slideToggle`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
    $(".toggle_container").hide();

    //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
    $("h9.trigger").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow", function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                map = InitMap(null, 'map', centerCoord, true); // initialize the map on default location
            }
        });
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });

    handle_clicks(); // click events handling by jQuery    
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/A5jnV/