# jQuery toggle interferes with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, toggle

I already asked the same question here, but didn't know what the problem was back then.

I now found out that jQuery's `toggle` function interferes with the Google Maps API, that's why the map isn't displayed correctly.

Optimally the map should load when the site loads, but only be displayed when the `toggle` function gets called. Would be okay as well, if the map loads again each time the `toggle` function gets called.

This is the code for the map showing a simple route:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div style="width: 600px;">
    <div id="map" style="width: 280px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoomControl: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var punkt = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://team3.digital-cultures.net/pic/whitedot.svg',
        new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 10));

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.249343, 10.419109),
        map: map,
        icon: punkt,
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.230084, 10.401052),
        map: map,
        icon: punkt,
    });
    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "START"
    });
    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "ZIEL"
    });

    infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
    infowindow2.open(map, marker2);

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: true,
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: "white",
            strokeWeight: 5
        }
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var requestroute = {
        origin: '53.249343, 10.419109',
        destination: '53.230084, 10.401052',
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(requestroute, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });

    map.set('styles', [{
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#5dc8b1"
        }]
    }, {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }]);
</script>
```

This is the code for the toggle function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    
        $('.route').hide();
        $('a#showhideroute').click(function () {
            $('a#logout').toggle(0);
            $('.route').slideToggle(400);
            $('a#showhideroute').toggleClass('active');
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });

        $('.frage').hide();
        $('a#showhidefrage').click(function () {
            $('.frage').toggle(400);
        });

        $('.users').hide();
        $('#user1').hide();
        $('#user2').hide();
        $('#user3').hide();
        $('a#showhideuser').click(function () {
            $('.users').finish(true, false).fadeToggle(200);
            $('#user1').finish(true, false).slideToggle(400);
            $('#user2').finish(true, false).slideToggle(400);
            $('#user3').finish(true, false).slideToggle(400);

        }).finish(true, false);

});
```

So when the link "showhideroute" is clicked, the class "route" is opened, in which the map is displayed.

I've found these questions adressing the same problem, but couldn't transfer the solutions to my code:

[Google maps in toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370649/google-maps-in-toggle)

[Google Maps v3 API + jQuery conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655347/google-maps-v3-api-jquery-conflict)

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IS3X.png) is how it should look], [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5ukv.png) is how it actually looks

Comment: Okay, got it! Solution was to load the map only, when toggle is called.